# blueimp gallery doesn't display big picture

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig, blueimp

I try to display some pictures with the blueimp gallery, but I have a little problem with : The miniatures are correctly load but when I click on it, I'm redirected to the page of this picture and is not displayed.

This is my code in a twig file (don't pay attention to the imagine_filter, it's just to resize the picture):

```
    <div class="row">
        <div id="show-img">
            <div id="blueimp-gallery" class="blueimp-gallery blueimp-gallery-carousel blueimp-gallery-controls">
                <div class="slides"></div>
                <a class="prev">‹</a>
                <a class="next">›</a>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>

      {% if question.images|length > 0 %}
          <div id="gallery">
              <hr>
              {% for image in question.images %}
                  <a href="{{ image.path|imagine_filter('sylius_extra_large') }}" title="{{image.altTag}}" data-gallery>
                      <img class="img-rounded" src="{{ image.path|imagine_filter('sylius_small') }}" alt="{{ image.alttag }}" />
                  </a>
              {% endfor %}
          </div>

          <script>
              document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);
                  function init() {
                      blueimp.Gallery(
                          document.getElementById('gallery').getElementsByTagName('a'),
                          {
                              container: '#blueimp-gallery',
                              carousel: false,
                              disableScroll: false,
                              hidePageScrollbars: false
                          }
                      );
                  };
            </script>
        {% endif %}
```

Did I miss something ?
Thank you in advance for you help

Comment: The script is included ? Is blueimp defined ?

Comment: Just find why doesn't work, the block script is override. Add a {{ parent() }} in the {% block javascripts %} and it work perfectly